# URL regex with optional params

Tags: regex, url

I am working on URL re-writing with regex. I have a few scenarios of

/register
/register?x=1

/register/
/register/?x=1

Currently I have `^/(.*)/(\?.+)$` but it is not correct

Comment: Always specify what language you're using for a regex. They vary between languages.

Answer (score 0):

The last part should be optional, but not repeatable.

```
^/(.+)/?(\?.+)?$
```

**gpojd** was close.

You may also want to specify the URL contents, and make sure they're not empty:

```
^/\w+/?(\?\w+=\w+)?$
```